# Find all itemprop in html with regex <(?<balise>.+)>(?(balise).*itemprop=.*)

Tags: html, regex

Hello i got some html and i try with a regex to find all HTML tag whoe get the itemprop attribute.

I would like to do with regex because i am not sure of the integrity of the HTML.

I have try this regex.

```
<(?<balise>.+)>(?(balise).*itemprop=.*)
```

I would like to match a pattern in my group, but it's not working.

Someone can help me

Example of text parse

```
<meta itemprop="currency" content="CDN" >
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head><span itemprop="name">My name</span>
```

I need to extract only html tag whoe get itemprop

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: It would help to include the **sample input** and **expected output** along with your result and details about why it's not working.

Comment: @AndyLester The OP did not use the PHP tag, RegEx is not what it started out anymore, it can be used for much more than parse 'regular languages' and in specific situations is actually the preferred method, for more info read [NikiC's blog post](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com has examples for more than PHP.

Comment: @kaᵠ The blog post is interesting for people who only know the basics of regular expressions but it’s not really relevant here. You should not try to parse HTML with regex, full stop. The article’s last sentence is not supported by arguments or evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, using regex to parse html is far from ideal and you should consider using an appropriate framework.

However, if insisting on using regex you could try something along the lines of:

```
(?<=<)\s*([^\s>]+?)(?=\s[^>]*(?<=\s)itemprop="[^<]*?/?>)
```

Looks for a string consisting of `zero or more whitespace characters followed by one or more non whitespace and non > characters`, said string has to be preceded by a `<` and followed by (in the given order): `a whitespace`, `zero or more non > characters`, `itemprop=" preceded by a space`, `zero or more non < characters`, `optional /`,`>`.

The above regex will not ensure that the tag's attributes are correctly balanced with regards to `'` and `"`, nor will it fail if it contains illegal characters/syntax. It will only assert that the tag has a start, a name consisting of more than whitespaces, a itemprop attribute and that the tag is closed.

Comment: Thank for your answer. In fact there is the regex i was needed <\s*([^\>]+)(?<=)itemprop=[^>]*/?> but i start with your. Thank

Comment: There is my latest one :-) <(?<tag>\w+)\s*([^\>]+)(?<=)itemprop=(?<s>"|').+\k<s>[^>]*>[^>]+</\k<tag>>|<\s*([^\>]+?)(?<=)itemprop=(?<s>"|').+\k<s>[^>]*/?>